# SQLite file empty when user downloads from store (windows universal)

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, uwp, win-universal-app

So I know the tittle is a bit weird but I don't know how to explain my question in the title.

So what I'm trying to ask is this:
I am building an app that solves chemistry questions. So I have a database that contains all elements including their information. So it looks like this.

```
public class PeriodicSystem
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(4)]
    public string Abbreviation { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(6)]
    public int Protons { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(6)]
    public int Electrons { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(6)]
    public double Mass { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(2)]
    public int Group { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(2)]
    public int Period { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(2)]
    public bool Metal { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

I have a .SQLite file which contains all this information. So my question is will all the information be in the SQLite file when people download the app or will it be empty? Because if it's empty the app won't be able to work.

Sorry for the bad English.

Comment: Why should the installer do anything with your database? Why would you assume, that anyone has written code for the installer, only to delete your database entries after successful installation?

Comment: Because I use git in visual studio and when my friends do a pull (to sync changes made) all changes that I did to the SQLite file are not shown in their file.

Comment: Lord... Do you understand, how computers work? If your local changes don't make it into your Git repository, then clearly you have misconfigured your Git client. It's unclear how that is supposed to have any effect on users downloading your app package from the store (or elsewhere).

Comment: Calm your tits.. I'm not an expert in this kind of stuf. But thanks for the answer anyway.

Comment: You don't need to be an expert in this kind of stuff. You just have to be capably of applying logic to a problem you don't know the solution to yet. You failed the latter part, and that is way more alarming than not being an expert at something.

Answer (score 0):

> So my question is will all the information be in the SQLite file when people download the app or will it be empty

This depend on where you put the SQLite database file on. By default, all apps can access the following two locations, Application install directory and Application data locations. If you put the database file on Application install directory, once you install the app on one device, the database will exist on the install directory. But pay attention this directory is **read only.** For how to access this directory and more details please reference [File access permissions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions).

> Because I use git in visual studio and when my friends do a pull (to sync changes made) all changes that I did to the SQLite file are not shown in their file.

For this comment, if you mean the changes for the SQLite didn't be pulled down by other people that must be that you don't push the updates of the SQLite file to Git. Since you are using git in visual studio, the SQLite file may not be in the project in visual studio so push updates of the project may not also push the SQLite file. I guess your SQLite file is saved in [local folder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br241621) of Application data locations as I mentioned above(if you on the PC device you may find it on `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Packages\{your app package}\LocalState`), it should be not under Git management.